# Moving SSL Certificate from one Apache server to another

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

I just moved hosts and I looked for a decent guide on how to move my SSL certificate from my old host to the new one.

I am amazed on how many 'guides' or 'tutorials' which are simply useless are out there.

Anyone has any link in his favorites or knows of a simple step by step guide on how to move the certificate?

I'm on Ubuntu and it's an unmanaged server, so no cpanel/plesk, just root ssh.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the old server? Or just a web control panel? Also, did you purchase the SSL certificate yourself?

Comment: I purchased it myself and I do have ssh access to the old server

Answer (score 4):

John,

Look in your apache conf file on the old server under the SSL section. You are looking for similar entries. This basically tells you the path of the certificate and the key file.

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

Copy the certificate (.crt file) and key over to your new server and follow the steps of configuring SSL with apache. The below mentioned link has steps to setup SSL w/Apache on Ubuntu. You can skip the section on generating a certificate.

http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Apache2_SSL_in_Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your virtual host config file on your old server for the domain in question. You will see some paths to some certificates.

Copy these certs over to the new server, and update the vhost config file for the domain in the new server to include these certificate files.